# How to delete asset from hyperledger fab test-network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to run test_network on hyperledger fabric node release 2.4. See here: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/test_network.html#interacting-with-the-network.

I can query the network using ReadAsset and UpdateAsset function.

However, the DeleteAsset function using below query doesn't work.

peer chaincode query -C mychannel -n basic -c '{"Args":["DeleteAsset","idOfasset"]}'

where, idOfasset is the ID or key of asset I am trying to delete from ledger.

Second, if the command would execute, would I be deleting the asset from the world database or the state database?
Or let's put it the other way when I execute ReadAsset where does it read from i.e from the world state or the channel state database?

Help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting an asset changes the state of the asset. For any kind of operations which involve modification of the state of the variables, the `invoke` command is used. Each "Invoke" transaction will be added to the "block" in the ledger. `query` is used when you just want to query the chaincode for reading the current value of an asset. So use, `invoke` in lieu of `query` in your command.

Coming on to your second question

> Second, if the command would execute, would I be deleting the asset from the world database or the state database? Or let's put it the other way when I execute ReadAsset where does it read from i.e from the world state or the channel state database?

World and state databases are the same things which are your CouchDB/LevelDB.
From Hyperledger Fabric's documentation:

> there’s a world state – a database that holds current values of a set of ledger states. The world state makes it easy for a program to directly access the current value of a state rather than having to calculate it by traversing the entire transaction log

You can read more about it [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/ledger/ledger.html).

Hyperledger Fabric doesn't actually "remove" the asset when a delete operation is performed. Blockchain is immutable and no data on a blockchain will ever be deleted. A deletion is just another transaction saying certain data is deleted so that the world state database can remove that data.

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49231474/does-hyperledger-remove-asset-actually-remove-anything) for more info.

Comment: It does make sense. I am able to view the world state but the blockchain seems inaccessible, which is why I am unable to see the new transaction created as a result of executing my Delete command, hence, the consusion.